# How to differentiate action for SearchView submit based on Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, search-suggestion

I have multiple fragments in my app. I want to add search function to may app. When i add search view in toolbar, the listener is in MainActivity. The problem is when i submit the query, the action for every fragment is same. Can i differentiate the action for every fragment ?
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess you have added the `SearchView` in Activity through menu.

If so then you can implement the menu inside each fragment instead of Activity. Then you can get Search functionality for each fragment.

To enable `Option Menu` for fragment you have to override `onCreate` like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Then you have to inflate your menu in 
`onCreateOptionsMenu` like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```